# Rotating a segment along a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, line

I would like to draw a line, something like

```
\coordinate (A) at (0.42,0.5);
\coordinate (B) at (0.98,0.44);
\draw[ultra thick] (A) -- (B);
```

and draw a sequence of small segments on this line where

1. the first is centred at (B),
2. the second is a bit further on the direction of (A) and a bit rotated,
3. the thirst a bit further than the second and a bit more rotated,...

and so on up to point (A).

I ended up with the following code, but it does not work at all.

```
\foreach \i in {0,0.1,..,1}{%
   \node [draw, rotate=180*\i] at (A)!\i!(B) {%
       \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw (-0.1,0) -- (0.1,0);
       \end{tikzpicture}};
}
```

Extra comments: the angles of the small segments at (B) and (A) should be under control. For example, I would like to draw a sequence of segments that rotates 180º or a sequence that rotates 720º

[image: Example]

Comment: The code doesn't work because (1) you nest `tikzpicture`s, and (2) your coordinate need to be surrounded by round brackets.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know what you mean by "you nest `tikzpictures`"

Comment: You put a `tikzpicture` inside a Ti*k*Z node, which is never recommended and which can easily produce errors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you mean but you can take this as a starting point

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (3,0);
\coordinate (b) at (0,1);
\draw (a) -- (b);
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,10} {
    \coordinate (x) at ($(a)!{\i/10}!(b)$);
    \draw ($(x)+({90-(4.5*\i)}:0.5)$) -- ($(x)+({-90-(4.5*\i)}:0.5)$);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can build a macro based on this code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (3,0);
\coordinate (b) at (0,1);
\draw (a) -- (b);
\def\beginangle{85}
\def\endangle{143}
\def\leng{1}
\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
    \coordinate (x) at ($(a)!{\i/10}!(b)$);
    \draw ($(x)+({\beginangle-((\beginangle-\endangle)*\i/10)}:{\leng/2})$) -- (x) coordinate[pos=2] (y) (x) -- (y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is a great starting point

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: a version using `decorations.markings`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotated bar step/.initial=0.0499,
rotated bar length/.initial=2mm,
rotated bar start angle/.initial=90,
rotated bars/.style={%
postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rotated bar step} with 
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\barangle}{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence
number}-1)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rotated bar step}*#1+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rotated bar start angle}}
\draw (\barangle:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rotated bar length}/2)
-- (\barangle+180:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rotated bar length}/2);}}}}]
 \draw[rotated bars=720] (0,1) -- (3,0);
 \draw[rotated bar length=4mm,rotated bar step=0.0999,rotated bars=720] (4,1) to[bend left] (7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is also nice. Unfortunately, I do not understand that much the code.
Are the initial and final segments always perpendicular to the line?
Can we control the number of segments on the line?

Comment: @MonLau In this example they are since `rotated bar start angle=90` and the difference between initial and final angle, i.e. the argument of `rotated bars`, is an integer multiple of 360. For different choices of these keys they are in general not.

Comment: @marmot I thought it was `rotated bär start angle = 90` :) @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @JouleV Doesn't wörk with pdflatex. ;-)

Comment: @marmot You used wrong engine. It _does_ work with pdflätex. I just checked.

Comment: @marmot, Thanks, I see. And the number of segments on the line is controlled by `rotated bar step`, right?

Comment: @MonLau Yes. And I use 0.0999 instead of 0.1 since for 0.1 the last line gets dropped (due to rounding errors).